# How to chose tick frequency on plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap date axis?

Tags: python, datetime, plotly, plotly-python

The title really said it all, I have this plot of a dataframe with a datetime index with 1 row every 15 minutes a list of strings for columns and binary values in the cells:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Heatmap(x=df.columns,
                       y=df.index,
                       z=df.values,
                       colorscale=[[0, 'rgb(248,105,107)'], [1, 'rgb(99,190,123)']],
                       xgap=1,
                       ygap=1,
                       # yperiod = f'{1000*60*15}', #1000 milliseconds / second, 60 seconds per minute, 15 minutes per row.
                       showscale=False)
            ])
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed" # earliest date on top, latest date down below.
```

Changing the value for yperiod doesn't change the number of periods, it only shifts them by a tiny little bit. The documentation calls for 'M' with  in milliseconds between every y axis tick. If I use the M in the string the heatmap thinks I'm talking about months and I get a very long y axis.

Please help me get this to have 1 tick per row, it really shouldn't be very hard, nothing needs to be computed, just the index shown.

Comment: sample data frame.  index is a datetime I guess, but don't know.  columns is a list of strings.  your code sample looks problematic.  `fig` is assigned then you manipulate `pte_fig_new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulated a dataframe that I believe matches your structure. Have included four different parameters

1. `tick0` set to first time in index
2. `dtick` work out number of milliseconds between first and second times in index
3. `reversed` appears your code was trying to do this
4. `tickformat` only want hours & minutes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

S = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range("1-nov-2021", periods=S, freq="15min"),
    data=np.random.uniform(1, 100, [S, 5]),
    columns=list("ABCDE"),
)

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Heatmap(
            x=df.columns,
            y=df.index,
            z=df.values,
            colorscale=[[0, "rgb(248,105,107)"], [1, "rgb(99,190,123)"]],
            xgap=1,
            ygap=1,
            # yperiod = f'{1000*60*15}', #1000 milliseconds / second, 60 seconds per minute, 15 minutes per row.
            showscale=False,
        )
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis={
        "tick0": df.index.min(),
        "dtick": (df.index[1] - df.index[0]).total_seconds() * 1000,
        "autorange": "reversed",
        "tickformat": "%H:%M",
    }
)
```

[image]